# Flask: display a dataframe by using dataTables.js

Tags: jquery, html, dataframe, flask, datatables

All I want to do is to show a dataframe on web after clicking a button. I'm using `flask` and tried to use `dataTables.js`. But I am pretty new to all these tools TAT

So until now, my output is: after clicking the button, I jump to `./extract` page, and all the data are shown like this:

> {
>     "my_table": "\n  \n    \n      trade_date\n      rem_period\n      bond_code\n      bond_name\n      bond_rating\n      bond_yield\n      note\n      offer\n      bid\n      amount\n    \n  \n  \n    \n      2018-04-04\n      8d\n      1382161\n      13\u6e1d\u6c34\u6295MTN1\n      AA+/AAA\n      3.6\n      None\n      \u56fd\u5bff\u517b\u8001\n      \u94f6\u534e\u57fa\u91d1\n      1000\n    \n    \n      2018-04-04\n      39d\n      1382227\n      13\u9ec4\u65c5\u6e38MTN1\n      AAA\n      4.6\n      None\n      \u4e2d\u6b27\u57fa\u91d1\n      \u5706\u4fe1\u6c38\u4e30\n      3000\n    \n    \n      2018-04-04\n      99d\n      101356002\n      13\u6e1d\u5bccMTN001\n      AAA\n      4.4\n      None\n      \u56fd\u5bff\u517b\u8001\n

However, what I want is that the table displays on the index page with the correct table format. Could you have a look on what the problem is?

views.py

```
@app.route('/extract', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def extract_excel():
    file = request.files['file']
    filename = file.filename
    database_name = FiveComps
    ...

        df = df[df['trade_date'] == request.form['upload_date']]
        return jsonify(my_table=df.to_html(classes='table table-striped" id = "a_nice_table', index=False, border=0))
    return render_template("index.html")
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bond</title> 
    <script src="static/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
    <!-- DataTables CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <!-- DataTables -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#showtable').bind("click", function(){
          $.getJSON('/extract', function(data){
            $("#mytablediv").html(data.my_table);
            $('#a_nice_table').DataTable();
          });
        });  
    });
    </script>     

  </head>  

  <body> 
    <div>
      <form action="/extract" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file"></input>
        <input type="text" name="upload_date" placeholder="2018-01-01"></input>
        <button type="submit" id="showtable">Preview</button>
      </form>
      <div id="mytablediv">Here should be a table</div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I omitted some unrelated code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using pandas? check out the docs here on styling https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#
Then you can just use:

```
html_string = df.style.render()
```

pass this to jinja2 template and render as raw html safe.

```
{{html_string|safe}}
```